# Networking debuging

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

How to systematically find culprit behind loss of internet in linux?

## I do know

that to to download files/access webpage/use ssh/etc , there are several layers of communication made: application,transport,internet,link ( [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) )

## I don't know

- How each of these layers (excluding `application` layer) map to programs/components in linux?
- How to check each of these components efficiently - if they are working correctly?
- In which order to check them

## My goal is

to have (reasonably) simple system for tracking down the problem.  In pseudo code it would look something like

```
 for(component in A..Z) // from hardwarefailure,missing drivers to configuration in /etc/network/interfaces
 {
     if  cmd_to_check(component).output == _OK_
     then continue // problem is 100% not here, continue with next item
     else break    // problem is 100% with current component
 }
 do_adhoc_reseach_on(item)
 fix(item)
```

I want to focus here on problems which happens on **MY** machine, not problems with remote or intermediary servers

### Notes

If there are differences

- between distributions, **debian** is preferred
- between wire vs wireless then **wire** is preferred
- between any other aspect, then most standard is preferred

If available free resources would be preferred

Thanks in advance for any answers and/or references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steps for testing the Internet connectivity:

- test if the Ethernet links is up and has the expected negotiated speed and duplex: `ethtool eth0`
- test if the next hop (neighbor router) is available: `ping -c 3 next_hop_ip`
- test if a well known remote site is available (e.g. ping the google DNS): `ping -c 3 8.8.8.8`
- test if the DNS is working: `host www.google.com`
- test if a website is answering: `wget -O - http://www.google.com`
- if the workstations are directly connected you should be able to see them with arp even if a firewall is configured on them: `sudo arping workstation_ip`
- test if workstations are reachable from the server: `ping workstation_ip`

When you fail one step, try to find what is happening before going to next one.